# Adding Edge Loops to Meshes created with Skin

Tags: modeling

This is my first time using skin in Blender (I'm following a tutorial). I'm stuck at a point where the tutorial suggests creating an edge loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on the mesh in *Edit Mode*, running down the middle of the character.

However, the "skin" mesh is not selectable, so when I try to create my loop I only get a single vertex showing up as selected and it creates a loop around the character instead of down the middle.

This is the [tutorial I am following](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/hardware_and_creative/9781783984886/2/ch02lvl1sec16/editing-the-mesh) under "How to Do It". My character is below - I'm trying to create an loop vertically from tip to tip. Any feedback is appreciated!

[image: My character]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a step from the previous page. The first line reads -

> Once we have applied the Skin and Armature modifiers, we are left with an almost ready-to-use base mesh

You don't have the real mesh to add a loop cut because you haven't applied the skin and armature modifiers. Click the apply button on each modifier to get the mesh you can edit further.

[image: apply modifiers]